# Как очистить input type=file в Internet Explorer 10 и ниже

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, файлы, form, input

Если задать `value = ''`, то это не очищает в `ie 10` и ниже.

Если же обернуть `input` в форму, вызвать её метод `reset()`, а потом вернуть `input` на место, то это тоже не очищает `input`. Внешне кажется, что он очищен, но `FileList` остается тот же наполненный файлами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение от Maxmaxmaximus:

```
input.type = '' // временно меняем тип input
input.type = 'file' // возвращаем тип input
```

P.S. Это `$('#file').replaceWith($('#file').clone());` не очищает инпат, а заменяет его на новый.

Answer (score 1):

Так должно помочь

```
$('#file').replaceWith($('#file').clone());
```

Comment: Ты не очищаешь его, а заменяешь новым)